# Finding the limit of $a_n = \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{2^2}{2}+...+\frac{2^{n}}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We have to prove the convergence and find the limit of $a_n = \frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{2^2}{2}+...+\frac{2^{n}}{n}\right)$. I tried to find $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_{n}$ and got $a_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{2(n+1)}\left(a_n+1\right)$ and could not proceed further.Any help is appreciated.
Edit : Following K.defaoite's answer limit appears to be 1 . But we still need to prove convergence.

Comment: Perhaps the Cesaro Stolz Lema could help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I see what needs to be done here. Denote the sum in brackets by $S_n$

$$S_n = \left(\frac{2}{1}+\frac{2^2}{2}+...+\frac{2^{n}}{n}\right)$$

First we prove by induction (for $n \ge 4$) the following:

$$S_n \gt \frac{ 2^{n+1} (n+2)}{(n+1)n} \tag{1}$$

Then using (1) it is easy to prove by induction that:

(2) the sequence is decreasing for $n\ge4$ i.e. $a_n \gt a_{n+1}$

(3) $a_n \ge 1$ for $n\ge4$ (that is even true for every $n$ but for us it's enough that it's true for $n\ge4$)

Once these two statements are proved, the convergence follows.
And then you take limits (that's the easy part as K.defaoite showed) and you're done.

Here is how using (1) we can prove the sequence is decreasing: we have $a_n=\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}S_n$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}S_{n+1}$ $=\dfrac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}(S_n+\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1})$. Now, the condition that $a_n\gt a_{n+1}$ is that $\dfrac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}S_n\gt \dfrac{n+2}{2^{n+2}}(S_n+\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1})$; this is equivalent to $2(n+1)S_n\gt (n+2)(S_n+\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1})$, which is equivalent to $nS_n\gt \dfrac{(n+2)2^{n+1}}{n+1}$ (subtract $(n+2)S_n$ from either side), and dividing this by $n$ gives (1).

Comment: I see you accepted my answer. Does it all work fine? Seems to me everything works trivially once one realizes to prove (1) first. Nice problem.

Comment: Yeah, I checked my computations, it all works fine.

Comment: I may be confused here, but how do you prove the sequence is decreasing based on a lower bound for the sum?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I just write it $a_n > a_{n+1}$ and I rework this inequality algebraically using (1) and also using that $S_{n+1} = S_n + 2^{n+1}/(n+1)$. And it turns out that it's true. In fact this inequality $a_n > a_{n+1}$ is what gave me the idea to prove (1).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I added a photo, you can take a look. I will remove it later as I know using such photos is discouraged here.

Comment: Ahh! That makes excellent sense. I can TeXify that...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please... thanks a lot, I am not good at this kind of stuff. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Very nice! Indeed my part was quite easy :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $a_n$ has a limit, which it appears to have, and your recursive expression is correct, which it appears to be, we can write
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+2}{2(n+1)}(a_n+1)$$
$$x=(x+1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\right)$$
$$x=\frac{x+1}{2}$$
$$x=1$$

Comment: Can you help in proving convergence

Comment: @sn24 Unfortunately I have not done sequence analysis for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (the equivalent for sequences of [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)),$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k}{k}}{\tfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tfrac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\tfrac{n2^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\tfrac2n)=1.$$